# ng-model to work on onChange event

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Today, using AngularJs, this line of code will work on the key-up event:

```
<input id="place" type="text" ng-model="place" />
<span>{{place}}</span>
```

But if I change the value of the input using a script, such:

```
$('#place').val('new value');
```

than nothing happens and the model doesn't change.

Any idea how to overcome this problem?

Comment: you should not be changing model values by dom traversing, you should change the model variable value from angular js controller when required, read angularjs documentation

Comment: @BurhanUddin I'm using jquery AutoComplete witch enters the selected value to the input.

Answer (score 0):

changing a value programatically of a form element does not trigger events, you need to trigger them after you set the value

```
$('#place').val('new value').change();
```

Am not familiar enough with angular to know if this is the data binding event needed